# How to turn off WriteFilter on WinNT4

Tags: write-protect, windows-nt-4

On a PC that has *Windows NT4 Embedded*, WriteFilter is activated. All the changes I make to C: partition are reverted after a reboot.

HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\wfilter is set to **"0"**

I have tried below method from [here](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1681&p=52850), but I got "File is already open" error when I try to load hive:

> Open Regedt32, select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then "File -> Load Hive",
> select the \winnt\system32\config\SYSTEM file on the NTe partition,
> name the hive "a" and then go to
> HKLM\a\ControlSet001\Services\wfilter. Double click on "Start" in the
> right pane, change the value to "4".
>
> Select "a" again, "File -> Unload Hive" and reboot into NTe. If
> everything went okay, the write filter should now be disabled. You can
> test that by creating a text file on the desktop and rebooting. It
> should still be there.

How do I disable Write Filter on a system that has write filter enabled?

Comment: Did you perform, "1. Boot your NT4 install again (that one you initially used to liberate the image)"?

Comment: No, I have no idea what that means :(

Comment: I did not say that I have not RTFM.. I said I have no idea what it means. I have read it but did not understand..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by following procedure:

- Open the WinNT4 medium (CF-card in my case) on an another host windows machine.
- Open Regedt32, select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then "File -> Load Hive", select the \winnt\system32\config\SYSTEM file on the NTe partition, name the hive "a" and then go to HKLM\a\ControlSet001\Services\wfilter. Double click on "Start" in the right pane, change the value to "4".
- Select "a" again, "File -> Unload Hive"